# Using NULLIF to divide by zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the error I'm receiving below:

```
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Having looked around at solutions it looks like I need to use NULLIF or ISNULL, I'm just unsure as to how to include it within the line below.

```
select  
min(round(OnCallTime*100/TotalTime,1)) as total
```

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` in denominator like below:

```
select  
min(round((OnCallTime*100/NULLIF(TotalTime,0)),1)) as total
```

So, whenever `TotalTime` is zero, it'll be replaced by `NULL` and you will not get the error of `Division by Zero`.

Answer (score 1):

So in the event TotalTime=0 what do you want to display?. I suggest NULL since divide by zero is not defined?.

You can write the query as follows

```
select  
       min(round( 
                  (OnCallTime*100)
                  / (case when TotalTime =0 then null else TotalTime end)
                ,1
                )
            ) as total
```

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce()` function

```
select  
min(round(OnCallTime*100/coalesce(TotalTime,1),1)) as total
```

Comment: Divide by zero error means denominator is zero. In this case it won't work.

Comment: what coalesce(TotalTime,1)  will rerurn ? does it return 0 ?? @saravanatn

Comment: if TotalTime=null means it will take it as 1. But TotalTime=0 means anything divide by zero is infinity right?

Answer (score 0):

use `coalesce()`  which return 1st non null value

```
select min(round((OnCallTime)*100/coalesce(TotalTime,1),1)) as total
```

Comment: Divide by zero error means denominator is zero. In this case it won't work.